# grep an array from other array in perl

Tags: arrays, linux, perl, grep

i have two array in my perl 
and i want to grep one array from other array my code in perl is as follows.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl  
open (han5, "idstatus.txt");  
open (han4, "routename.txt");  
@array3 = <han4>; 
 @array4 = <han5>;  
foreach (@array3) { 
@out = grep(/$_/, @array4); 
print @out; }
```

**file routename.txt**

```
strvtran
fake
globscr
```

**file idstatus.txt**

```
strvtran online   
strvtran online  
strvtran online
globscr online 
globscr online
globscr online  
globscr online  
globscr online 
Xtech dead  
Xtech dead  
fake online  
fake online  
fake connecting
walkover123 online  
walkover123 online
```

Now what i want to grep **globscr** element from idstatus.txt and output should be like:

```
globscr online 
globscr online
globscr online  
globscr online  
globscr online
```

and i dont want to use any system command. please help me here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not removing the newlines, so your match is including a newline in what it is looking for.

You also need to make the for loop use a different variable, since inside the grep, `$_` will only refer to the element of the list given to grep currently being inspected.

Try:

```
chomp(@array3 = <han4>);
@array4 = <han5>;  
foreach my $routename (@array3) { 
    @out = grep(/$routename/, @array4); 
    print @out;
}
```

This will output:

```
strvtran online   
strvtran online  
strvtran online
fake online  
fake online  
fake connecting
globscr online 
globscr online
globscr online  
globscr online  
globscr online
```

I'm not sure what you mean by wanting to grep globscr from idstatus.txt; what role does routename.txt play then?

Comment: file idstatus has multiple element and and some the element exist in routename. eg. in idstatus.txt there is an element "strvtran online" and an element in routename.txt is "strvtran". so i want to grep "strvtran" from idstatus.txt and get the element of  idstatus.txt like "strvtran online"...... i have used your script but it is not displaying anything......

Comment: then you didn't use my script or your files are not what you say?  show exactly what you did run (edit your question)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `grep`ping each line, consider building a regex that contains the route names as alternations:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

open my $rnameFH, '<', 'routename.txt';
chomp( my @routename = <$rnameFH> );
close $rnameFH;

my $names = '(?:' . ( join '|', map { "\Q$_\E" } @routename ) . ')';
my $regex = qr /^$names/;

open my $idFH, '<', 'idstatus.txt';

while(<$idFH>){
    print if /$regex/;
}

close $idFH;
```

Output on your datasets:

```
strvtran online   
strvtran online  
strvtran online
globscr online 
globscr online
globscr online  
globscr online  
globscr online 
fake online  
fake online  
fake connecting
```

The script creates an OR-type regex, by `join`ing the route names with "|" (print `$names` to see this).  The `map` is there only to quote any meta-characters which may be in the names, e.g., `.*^`, etc., as these would impact the matching.

Hope this helps!